# How to pretty print JSON into a line based key structure?

Tags: php, json

Say I have an arbitrary nested JSON file:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
     {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
     {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
   ]
 }
}}
```

And I want to output the structure:

```
foo.menu.id=file 
foo.menu.value=File 
foo.menu.popup.menuitem[0].value=New 
foo.menu.popup.menuitem[0].onclick=CreateNewDoc()
foo.menu.popup.menuitem[1].value=Open
```

And so forth. My use case is that it will make easier to work with JSON APIs if I can get an overview of the keys I might want to use in my mashup.

How would I achieve that in PHP or nodejs? Or some other tool? If the text value is very long then it could be truncated to be nicely lines based.

Comment: slightly confused, how is this more useful? Just JSON.stringify an object to send it somewhere, JSON.parse that data back into an object, between those two points where is the need to see the structure? In even decently written code you shouldn't have to worry about the keys, you just make sure -as programmer- that they're there, then you use them.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(jsonstring))`; use the built-in object explorer in (modern) the browser's console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in most cases, you should simply parse JSON in the desired target language. If that's not an option, you can easily iterate over all elements, [like this](http://ideone.com/Qo5h0B):

```
<?php
function unroll_obj($o, $prefix='') {
    foreach ($o as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            unroll_obj($v, $prefix . $k . '.');
        } else {
            echo $prefix . $k . '=' . $v . "\n";
        }
    }
}

$s = '{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
     {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
     {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
   ]
 }
}}';

$o = json_decode($s, true);
unroll_obj($o);
```

Comment: Nice! Just what I was looking for. Be nicer if the numeric keys could have the square brackets for use in JS. Nonetheless I'll accept as is.

Comment: @hendry If you want to use it in JavaScript, **you don't need this code**! All JSON is valid JavaScript, so simply write out `echo 'var data = ' . $json . ';';`

Comment: Yes, but this helps me quickly find the key I want to use. :)

Comment: @hendry Are you aware of the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag? That makes the JSON quite readable as well.

Comment: Yes I am, but the output isn't line based like I like it here.